# Height of div based on Advanced Custom Fields date entries

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, height, advanced-custom-fields

I'm building a timeline page in Wordpress with Advanced Custom Fields. I have an event start date and end date and I need to adjust the height of a div based on the duration of the event.

The code I have so far is below. `<div class="span"></div>` is the div that needs the height. A guestimate of the height ratio I need is about 100px per 30.5 days. The field names of the start/end dates are `timeline_datespan_start` and `timeline_datespan_end` and the field type is Date Picker.

```
<?php 
  $custom_args = array(
      'post_type'       => 'timeline',
      'post_status'     => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page'  => -1,
      'meta_key'        => 'timeline_date',
      'orderby'         => 'meta_value_num',
      'order'           => 'ASC'
    );

  $custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_args ); ?>

<?php if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<!-- the loop -->
<?php while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>

    <!-- event span -->
    <?php 
        $timeline_span = get_field('timeline_datespan_start');
        if( !empty($timeline_span) ): ?>
        <div class="event <?php the_field('timeline_datespan_start'); ?>">
            <div class="timeline-event-span">
                <div class="span"></div><div class="line"></div>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> <span class="timeline-date">(<?php the_field('timeline_datespan_start'); ?> - <?php the_field('timeline_datespan_end'); ?>)</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <!-- /event span -->

    <?php // endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<!-- end of the loop -->

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else:  ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
  $startDate = the_field('timeline_datespan_start');
  $endDate   = the_field('timeline_datespan_end');

  $datetime1 = date_create($startDate);
  $datetime2 = date_create($endDate);

  $dDiff = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
  $height = ($dDiff->days) / 0.305;
```

Comment: Thanks but when I echo out `$height` I just get a value of 0.

Comment: What return `the_field('timeline_datespan_start')`? - it return valid date? When I use for ex. `$datetime1 = date_create('01.07.2017');` and `$datetime2 = date_create('10.08.2017');` it's works good.

Comment: Forgive me, my php skills are terrible. Maybe it's breaking because my date format is Y-m-d?

Comment: It works fine for me when date is for ex. `2017-08-10`

Comment: Maybe I have it implemented wrong? Again, I'm not very good at php...

I have your suggested code placed directly after `<?php while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
`

And have edited the div as:
`<div class="span" style="height: <?php echo $height ?>px;"></div>`

Comment: Maybe it's problem with veriables. Try this, i think now will works

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction.
Here's what got it working for me:

```
<?php 
    $startdate = get_field('timeline_datespan_start', false, false);
    $enddate = get_field('timeline_datespan_end', false, false);

    $startdate = new DateTime($startdate);
    $enddate = new DateTime($enddate);

    $dDiff = $startdate->diff($enddate);
    $height = ($dDiff->days) / 0.305;
?>
```